# M19 akimbo challenge, how do I get the counter to go up?

Tags: achievements, call-of-duty-warzone

The challenge says "Get 3 kills in 5 different matches using the 'Frangible-Wounding' perk".

- I equip M19 with frangible
- go to the team-deathmatch (free this weekend)
- I just played a game and got multiple kills 18 with M19
- but when I go to the M19 perks akimbo it still says 0 out of 5

How do I get the counter to go up?

Answer (score 1):

i think there was an issue with the video-game or server.

i just got back from another round and the counter went up by one. so i think i'm good.

---

UPDATE:

- last night i played about 20 games with the required gun+frangible-wounding and got about 20 kills each game
- but none of them counted towards the in-game counter
- today i log in play two games and both counted up from 3 out of 5 to 5 out of 5
- so i got the in-game challenge!

i don't know what changed but i think there are two possible reasons:

1. game doesn't let you progress 5 out of 5 in one day
2. game servers for some reason did not save my progress (which i've seen talk of...)

i don't know which reason is correct. both are just speculation.

but the important thing is that to get this perk you just need to have the weapon and the "frangible-wounding" and do 5 matches and get 3+ kills with the weapon in each match.

Comment: Please edit your answer if you want to add information.